# How can I set a different message value per condition in a django-rest-framework custom permissions class?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a permissions class similar to [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19313314/django-rest-framework-per-action-permission#34162842).

I'd like to set a different `message` value under different conditions. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class UserPermission(permissions.BasePermission):

    message = ""

    def has_permission(self, request, view):                                                        
        if some_condetion:
            self.message = "some message"
            return False                   
        else:
            self.message = "other message"
            return True
```

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions

Comment: Oops - missed 'self.'. Thanks! Only improvement on that answer, `message = ""` isn't required unless you'd like to set a new default.