# How to make Django REST User API with complex permissions

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to make a Django REST User API with complex permissions as follows:

**GET**

- Only Admin should be able to get all User data
- Logged in User should be to get himself and the names of other Users

**PUT**

- Only Admin and Self should be able to PUT
- Except for is_staff and is_superuser only is_superuser should be able to change the status of a user
- Password changes by a User should require the old password
- if User is !is_staff password reset should be possible

**POST / DELETE**

- Only Admin should be able POST/DELETE User
- User should be able to update his own Profile

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to control the view or serializer to allow such permissions. Is there a template how I can exactly control the permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write your custom permission according to DRF [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions).

And add `YourCustomPermission` in your view:

```
class ExampleView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (YourCustomPermission,)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. With your hint I was able to find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19313314/django-rest-framework-per-action-permission a very helpful post I could adept to my needs.

Comment: If my post was helpful, could you mark it as a solution. Good luck!